# Why would TickCount and the system clock progress at different rates?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, time

We had a location in our system where we wanted to check the last system boot time.  Seeing that the TickCount (GetTickCount64, no 49-day overflow problems here) was the number of milliseconds since boot, we decided to compute that last boot time by subtracting the TickCount in milliseconds from the current system time (as gotten from function _ftime64).

We encountered a problem in production that was traced to this area and found that the Windows Time-Service event log (Applications and Services Logs / Microsoft / Windows / Time-Service) events contained a TickCount that seems to be the same tick count accessible functionally, and the time the event was created, so we could use the events to reconstruct what the computed boot time would have been at the time of each event.  We found that on the affected system, this computed boot time was drifting forward about two seconds per day.  Checking the events on my own system showed the computed time drifting backwards about a third of a second per day.

The python script that I used for computing what the "event time minus tick count" boot time would be at each event was

```
import Evtx.Evtx as evtx
import Evtx.Views as e_views
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import datetime

def parseTimeEvents(evtxFile):
    events = []
    with evtx.Evtx(evtxFile) as f:
        for rec in f.records():
            xml = rec.xml()
            doc = ET.fromstring(xml)
            ns = '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}'

            time = doc.find(".//%sTimeCreated" % ns).get("SystemTime")

            ticks = None
            
            dataElems = doc.findall(".//%sEventData/%sData" % (ns,ns) )
            for de in dataElems:
                if de.get("Name") == "TickCount":
                    ticks = de.text

            # all events I saw in Time-Service log had TickCount
            if ticks:
                events.append( (time, ticks) )

    for (time,ticks) in sorted(events):
        currentTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        ticks = long(ticks)

        milli = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1)

        print( "%-35s%-18d%-35s" % (str(currentTime), ticks, str(currentTime - ticks * milli)))
```

A scattering of the results from a local system that systeminfo.exe says was last rebooted at (converted to utc) 2023-07-21 14:08:44:

```
2023-07-18 17:44:10.294693         2109578           2023-07-18 17:09:00.716693      
2023-07-19 01:42:09.412140         30788906          2023-07-18 17:09:00.506140     
2023-07-20 17:31:29.409824         174149921         2023-07-18 17:08:59.488824     
2023-07-21 02:37:37.296728         206918062         2023-07-18 17:08:59.234728        
2023-07-21 14:08:55.449699         11062             2023-07-21 14:08:44.387699    
2023-07-22 08:59:42.543713         67858296          2023-07-21 14:08:44.247713        
2023-07-23 14:34:38.582911         174354937         2023-07-21 14:08:43.645911     
2023-07-24 21:45:57.170725         286634125         2023-07-21 14:08:43.045725   
2023-07-25 16:02:37.229731         352434578         2023-07-21 14:08:42.651731      
2023-07-26 10:14:53.242479         417970984         2023-07-21 14:08:42.258479      
2023-07-27 16:47:34.296005         527932750         2023-07-21 14:08:41.546005               
2023-07-28 07:45:33.294981         581812015         2023-07-21 14:08:41.279981               
2023-07-29 01:57:49.315346         647348421         2023-07-21 14:08:40.894346         
2023-07-30 14:22:21.327190         778421218         2023-07-21 14:08:40.109190
```

The tick count resets as expected around the time of the actual reboot, but then the computed boot time regresses about half a second per day.

The code we're actually relying on to use this computed boot time is C++, but the results of a current execution of it line up with the python script's output for the most recent events, so I don't think there's any language or code-specific issues causing it to look like a drift (or if there are, they must be present in the python also, so I'd rather hear objections to that).

My initial suspicion was that time synchronization was to blame, but the logs of the machines I've looked at have only contained a few TMP_OPS_SET_TIME events and none of them say that they're applying a large enough adjustment frequently enough to account for this.

Do the TickCount and system clocks just advance at different rates, and it is incorrect to combine them this way and expect an accurate result for the last boot time?  Is there some system setting that affects this?

Trying to search for other people encountering this issue has mostly caught me problems with TickCount overflowing, which can't be the problem here.  I found one page talking about the TickCount and system clock updating at different times, but not that they would progress at different rates.

Comment: On looking at the events again, I think maybe time sync IS to blame; there weren't many TMP_OPS_SET_TIME (event id 261), but there were a lot of TMP_OPS_SET_TIME_ADJUSTMENT (event id 262) and further reading of those events / review of how time synchronization works suggests that time sync prefers to apply by updating the clock rate.  I suppose that update of the clock rate must not apply to the clock that TickCount comes from?